# Oracle SQL: getting only one max row using multiple criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have this table:

```
Department   NAME   EMAIL         ID     DATE1         DATE2
1            John   asd@asd.com   74     05/04/2007    05/04/2007
1            Sam    asd@asd.com   23     05/04/2007    05/04/2007
1            Tom    asd@asd.com   46     05/04/2007    03/04/2007
1            Bob    bob@asd.com   23     01/01/2006
2            Tom    asd@asd.com   62     02/02/2000    05/05/1997
```

I want to get the row (only one per department) with max `DATE1`, but it's not unique! So if there is multiple results I want to get the max `DATE2`, and if there are multiple ones then the one with the biggest ID is returned.

So there result of the query would be:

```
1            John   asd@asd.com   74     05/04/2007    05/04/2007
2            Tom    asd@asd.com   62     02/02/2000    05/05/1997
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use the ROW_NUMBER function:

```
SELECT Department, NAME, EMAIL, ID, DATE1, DATE2
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY DATE1 DESC, DATE2 DESC, ID DESC) AS RowNumber, 
       Department, NAME, EMAIL, ID, DATE1, DATE2
FROM MyTable ) t
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: it sound great! does it work for a partition by multiple columns? because my table is much more complicated

Comment: @user337746 - Yes, `partition by` works exactly as a `group by` statement does.

Comment: yes, partition by is similar to group by clause but for the Row_Number function

Comment: @user337746 Glad I can help, please don't forget to mark the correct answer for future reference

Comment: @BassamMehanni i tried it on oracle, there shouldn't be comma next to Department just space before Order BY and thanks for the solution.

Comment: @jero Fixed! Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 5):

Use the `over` clause:

```
select
    *
from
    (
    select
        Department,
        Name,
        Email,
        ID,
        DATE1,
        DATE2,
        max(DATE1) over (partition by Department) as MaxDate1,
        max(DATE2) over (partition by Department, DATE1) as MaxDate2,
        max(ID) over (partition by Department, DATE1, DATE2) as MaxID
    from
        employees
    ) x
where
    x.DATE1 = x.MaxDate1
    and x.DATE2 = x.MaxDate2
    and x.ID = x.MaxID
```

Comment: Nice, and pretty novel.  But wouldn't just using row_number would have less overhead?

Comment: @Dems - Absolutely it would. Wanted to give another way to do it if this was just an example and he needed more granular control.

Answer (score 0):

Something like....

```
SELECT y2.*
FROM
(SELECT dept, 
  MAX(
    TO_CHAR(date1,'YYYYHH24MISS') || TO_CHAR(date2,'YYYYHH24MISS') 
    || id) as lastrec
 FROM yourtable y1
 GROUP BY dept) as ilv,
 yourtable y2
 WHERE y2.id=TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(y2.lastrec, 21))
```

Comment: Ohhh, I get it.  But it does assume that the ID field is unique, which hasn't been state.  Nice latteral thinking though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT
    Department,
    Name,
    Email,
    ID,
    DATE1,
    DATE2,
    max(DATE1) over (partition by Department) as MaxDate1,
    max(DATE2) over (partition by Department, DATE1) as MaxDate2,
    max(ID) over (partition by Department, DATE1, DATE2) as MaxID
FROM
    employees
) 
WHERE
x.DATE1 = x.MaxDate1
AND x.DATE2 = x.MaxDate2
AND x.ID = x.MaxID
```